Is there a way to use the Enter/Return key to start a new line in ChatGPT without sending the existing (unfinished) text?
I'm very used to typing text on a Windows PC keyboard. The normal response to typing text is to use the Enter or Return keys. But ChatGPT's interfaces are different.
On an iPhone interface with ChatGPT, a line feed nicely matches by clicking on "return" and creating a new line in the message text being created. 
However, on a Windows PC, an Enter or Return keypress sends the existing (unfinished) text quite unceremoniously. This is a big waste of time, as it causes unwanted text to be generated by ChatGPT and a response repeat (and the original text being generated is lost).
Is there a workaround for this? I've looked for workarounds but can't find any. I've sent messages to OpenAI and don't see any response or action anywhere.

Have you try shift+enter or alt+enter?

shift+enter is the awkward solution that I have to use.  I've not tried alt+enter but the effect would be the same if that also works.

I now realize that I have been "composing" prompts using the web interface on ChatGPT.  And, I would much prefer to continue that way.  I've learned to use shift+enter but my brain often doesn't cooperate.  Thus this question.

I believe Shift+Enter is the simplest solution so far as compared to using third-party software.

Contrary to what you are saying this behavior is not uncommon with Windows apps.
You are comparing apples to oranges.
Your normal (apples) may be a Word Processing application where Enter is used for line breaks however countless Windows apps (oranges) use Enter to signify completion.
For example, I have bumped up against this in Excel when trying to insert a line break in a cell as well as in multiple chat applications where the message is submitted instead of inserting a line break.  Web apps behave like this commonly and I am often accidentally submitting chats and comments on this site because of this behavior.
If the Windows App or Web App doesn't support customizing the behavior of this key, there are keystroke capture apps for Microsoft Windows that can intercept Enter for a specific application or website and instead send Shift+Enter or whatever key combination is required to insert a line break.
I use Autohotkey myself and I'm sure there are others.

Apples = text editor type app and Oranges = Messaging app. I guess.  I didn't initially understand the reference.  So, yes.  I had not realized the significance of ChatGPT's prompt that says: Message ChatGPT... But then, I don't use Twitter, Slack or Facebook that much.

Is Autohotkey capable of recognizing a web interface or a particular web interface to toggle it's behaviors?  It seems that would be important.

@fred3 Yes. There is expansive online documentation as well as a very active user community forum with posts like website-specific hotkey script using Window Title or  another, based on URL, not Window Title

@fred3 "Apples = text editor type app and Oranges = Messaging app." To be more clear apples=Windows apps/Web Apps where enter adds a line break. oranges=Windows apps/Web Apps where it does not.  I think that word processing apps are an obvious example of apples, but as I indicated Excel suffers from the same issue you are bumping up against (enter submits changes rather than creating line breaks). The choice of behavior seems closely tied to whether the app is "waiting" for an indication of completion from the user. Some chat apps allow tweaking configuration to address our muscle memory.
